# Handwritten digit recognition using OVA using polynomial kernel perceptron method,and I'm constantly getting a KeyError: (0, []). what do I do?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mnist, keyerror

***This is the code that I am using for the OVA, and I'm constantly having this problem, and I can't understand why this is occuring.***

```
def train(self, train_set):

    # number of examples
    m = train_set.shape[0]
    train_y = train_set['label']
    train_x = train_set.drop(['label'],1)

    # Alphas store values of alpha for each class
    alphas = np.zeros(shape=(m, 10))
    train_gram = grammatrix(train_x, train_x, self.kernel, self.param)
    print(alphas: )
    # initialize w to store indexes of train examples that have non-zero alpha
    w = []
    # keep track of the best valid set error rate to stop training.
    best_train_err = 1.0
    best_w = []
    cont = True
    while cont:
        train_incorrect = 0
        for index in range(m):
            preds = np.einsum("ij, i", alphas[w, :], train_gram[index, w])

            y = [1 if j == train_y[index] else -1 for j in range(10)] * preds <= 0
            if np.any(y):
                y = y.astype(int)
                alphas[index, :] -= y * my_sign(preds)
                w.append(index) if index not in w else w

            y_hat = np.argmax(preds)

            if y_hat != train_y[index]:
                train_incorrect += 1
        train_err = train_incorrect / len(train_x)
        if train_err == 0:
            cont = False
            best_w = w
            best_train_err = train_err
        elif train_err <= best_train_err:
            cont = True
            best_w = w
            best_train_err = train_err
        else:
            cont = False

    self.alphas = alphas[best_w, :]
    self.x = train_x[best_w, :]
    self.y = train_y[best_w]
    self.w = best_w

    return best_train_err
```

**And for those who are wondering what the grammatrix function is, its basically a function that help create the kernel matrix by returning the
kernel matrix.**

```
    def grammatrix(data1, data2, kernel, param):
    """
    :param data1:
    :param data2:
    :param kernel: "p" for polynomial
    :param param: kernel parameter, degree for polynomial
    :return:
    """
    if kernel == "p":
        gram = data1 @ data2.T
        gram = np.power(gram, param)

    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid kernel type.')
    return gram
```

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Rishav\Desktop\Statistical Method of ML Project\PROJECT-universiity\MNIST_KP.py", line 173, in <module>
    training_err = OVA.train(train_set)

  File "C:\Users\Rishav\Desktop\Statistical Method of ML Project\PROJECT-universiity\MNIST_KP.py", line 96, in train
    preds = np.einsum("ij, i", alphas[w, :], train_gram[index, w])

  File "C:\Users\Rishav\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\Rishav\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 388, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: (0, [])
```

What I don't understand is why am I getting a keyerror, like what is really happens in a keyerror? What's the problem with my code ?

Comment: What's `grammatrix`?

Comment: It is the user defined function I created to calculate the value of the polynomial kernel @richardec

Comment: Can you add its definition to the question?

Comment: if kernel == "p":
        gram = data1 @ data2.T
        gram = np.power(gram, param)  return gram

Comment: the grammatrix function basically returns the kernels which are then used to form the kernel matrix